# Beautiful Soup - Removing Outer Tags

Tags: python

I have an HTML doc that contains a bunch of `<div>`'s, with child `<p>`'s and inside `<href>`'s. The goal is this,

1. remove the `<div>` and `<p>` tags
2. at the end of each removed `<div>` add a `</br>`

**Example**

So that this:

```
<div> 
  <p>
    <a href="" id="tnt1">[1]</a>"RFC 4456 - BGP Route Reflection: An Alternative to Full ... - IETF Tools.">ref="https://example.com">https://https://example.com"</a></span><span>. Accessed 15 Nov. 2017.
  </p>
</div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<a href="" id="tnt1">[1]</a>"RFC 4456 - BGP Route Reflection: An Alternative to Full ... - IETF Tools.">ref="https://example.com">https://https://example.com"</a></span><span>. Accessed 15 Nov. 2017.
</br>
```

**Current**

So far my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for div in soup.find_all(name=re.compile(r'div')):
    print div
```

However all examples seem to point to replace the inner text rather then actual tags. Also if there is a way to do this in bs3, it would be ideal, as all of my other code is currently using v3.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Thanks,

Comment: can't you get directly `<a>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''.join(str(x) for x in div.p.contents)` gives me inner HTML as string on bs4

I get `parent = div.parent` to use it later

Using `div.extract()` I remove `div` with all subtags.

Using `parent.append()` I put inner HTML back .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<strong>
<div> 
  <p>
    <a href="" id="tnt1">[1]</a>"RFC 4456 - BGP Route Reflection: An Alternative to Full ... - IETF Tools.">ref="https://example.com">https://https://example.com"</a></span><span>. Accessed 15 Nov. 2017.
  </p>
</div>
</strong>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    parent = div.parent

    inner = ''.join(str(x) for x in div.p.contents) + "<br/>"
    print('--- inner ---')
    print(inner)

    # remove div with all subtags
    div.extract()

    parent.append(BeautifulSoup(inner, 'html.parser'))
    print('--- after ---')
    print(parent)
```

Result:

```
--- inner ---

<a href="" id="tnt1">[1]</a>"RFC 4456 - BGP Route Reflection: An Alternative to Full ... - IETF Tools.">ref="https://example.com">https://https://example.com"<br/>
--- after ---
<strong>

<a href="" id="tnt1">[1]</a>"RFC 4456 - BGP Route Reflection: An Alternative to Full ... - IETF Tools."&gt;ref="https://example.com"&gt;https://https://example.com"<br/></strong>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you then add this in place of the previous div

Comment: see new code - I use `div.extract()` to remove `div` and `parent.append()` to put inner HTML back.