# Return XML as is without adding outer p tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

After running beautifulsoup on an output from internal process, I some times see that my output has a outer `p` tag, for example : `<p>...</p>` in case of incorrect xml's. I know using string operations or using `soup.find("p").decode_contents()` I can fetch only internal html tags.

```
soup = bs(''.join(my_output), "lxml")
return soup.find("body").decode_contents()
```

My question is that I do not want beautifulsoup to add a `<p>` tag in case there is incorrect xml's and output should be returned as is. Please let me know if its possible ?
Please note that I need to use `lxml` parser only because that has worked for most of data sets.

Edit:
I know that I can use string manipulation or also use `soup.find("p").decode_contents()` to not include `p` tag, what I am looking for is that beautifulsoup itself should not add `p` tag and return me xml as is.

Comment: As I understand, do you want to remove tag `<p>` and keep what's inside this tag in-place how it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup - Removing Outer Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987622/beautiful-soup-removing-outer-tags)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη: Please see my edit..

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Yeah, correct.. but I am not sure when my xml output is incorrect which results in beautifulsoup adding p tag to make it a proper xml, when it does happen, then p tag should be not be added by beautifulsoup

Comment: @ArunShankar which `IDLE` you are using ? do you run your script via `python code.py`? and which OS ?

Comment: @ArunShankar maybe `unwrap()` is what are you looking for? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap

Comment: @AndrejKesely it's looks so.

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is to see if beautiful soup will not try to correct xml by adding p tag..